# Where is the JSON Config File for Discord Installed Via Snap?

Tags: snap, settings, javascript, json

The only .json files I can find are build_info and manifest (I don't think either of them are config files).

Forgive me if my question is too amateurish, I just installed Ubuntu recently. I'm trying to get this Javascript fix to work in Discord to properly block messages (https://github.com/Multarix/Discord-Hide-Blocked-Messages), and to access the developer console on the app, I need to access the settings.json file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo find . -type f -regex ".*discord.*settings.json"
```

gave me (flatpak discord install):

```
~/.var/app/com.discordapp.Discord/config/discord/settings.json
```

Comment: Helped me with this: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/9jllvp/linux_client_problem_with_window_snapping_and_how/

Answer (score 1):

I found mine here: `/home/username/snap/discord/132/.config/discord/settings.json`

Although your version number (eg, `132`) might be different.

There is also one in `current` which is a symbolic link from my version `132`: `/home/username/snap/discord/current/.config/discord/settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed discord via snap,
this is where you could find your JSON config file `/var/lib/snap/discord/current/config.json`